# Easy way to do multiple cherry-pics from a remote branch

Tags: git

I have a branch (A) which has 8 commits. Assume the last two commits were the one that corrupted this branch.

a.1 - a.2 - a.3 - a.4 - a.5 - a.6 - a.7 -a.8

Is there any easy way, in which I can create a separate branch having first 6 commits only, without cherry-picking each commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

`git checkout -b new-branch a.6`

`a.6` should of course be SHA-1 of the commit.

Comment: will this not pick only specific a.6 commit? or will it pick all a.1 to a.6 ?

Comment: All - it will create a new branch whose tip will be a.6

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked as expected. One more quick question, had it been some random commit that corrupted the branch, like 2, 5, 7 and then I had to cut out a branch, then any other option apart from specific cherry-pick?

Comment: You could reorganize order of commits `git rebase -i` to move the
offending commits to the tip of the branch but most probably you'd
have to solve several merge conflicts while doing this but otherwise
cherry-picking is the only way to go I think. Also notice that you can
cherry-pick a range of adjacent commits, see `man git-cherry-pick` and
`man gitrevisions`.